# Динамический файл index.php с динамическими доменами

Tags: php

У меня возник вопрос, когда я создавал сайт для одной компании. Мне нужно было сделать поддержку нескольких городов. Написал сайт и дублировал его на несколько папок с названиями: Владивосток.site, Москва.site, Волгоград.site и тд... И всё работает хорошо, но вопрос в том, что если бы у меня было не несколько городов, а 5000 или 11000. Создавать 11000 папок не самый лучший вариант решения такой задачи. Как быть?
Я думал решить эту задачу путём создание одного файла index.php и менять его подстраиваясь под город, но как быть с доменным именем? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть или что почитать на эту тему.

Comment: а wordpress здесь при чем?

Comment: у wordpress свои средства организации мультидоменности. Если вас интересует решение на основе этой программы, то это надо явно обозначать в вопросе, а не писать про какой-то  index.php. Если же не интересует, то не нужно добавлять этот тег.

Comment: Если это WordPress, то есть плагины типа такого: https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domain-mapping-on-single-site/

Answer (score 0):

Почитать вывод функции `phpinfo(INFO_VARIABLES)`. Там содержится куча сведений о том, какая именно информация доступны РНР скрипту.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` содержит ваш домен.